# Virtual servers not forwarding when DMZ set in DLink 2730B

Tags: router, routing, nat

My router is a [DLink 2730B](http://support.dlink.com.au/download/download.aspx?product=DSL-2730B). The target machine IP is `192.168.1.6`. I’ve applied DMZ Host to this IP, and have configured on 'Virtual Server' the following settings:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/YERGrfZ.png?1]

Port 21 on `192.168.1.6` is ok, I can access `192.168.1.6:21` from LAN. But when I try to access it using the WAN IP, the browser returns:

```
This webpage is not available

Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The external IP address is: `186.213.100.231`, FTP port is on 2121, as you can see in my router configuration.

Comment: Yes, try to access it ftp://186.213.100.231:2121/, if you try ftp://186.213.100.231:21/ it connects but I guess it's FTP is from the router, because, it's not accepting my credentials, and my credentials are correct, I'm using them to connect on LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you say that ports 8080, 8443 and 2121 cannot be reached from the outside world; meaning outside your network. And that you can reach ports 80, 443 and 21 from inside your network, correct?

Doing an `nmap` to the IP address you’ve provided of `186.213.100.231` shows none of the ports are open despite you setting them in the DMZ as you have described:

```
nmap 186.213.100.231 -p0,65535

Starting Nmap 6.25 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-11-12 17:37 EST
Strange error from connect (49):Can't assign requested address
Nmap scan report for 186.213.100.231.static.host.gvt.net.br (186.213.100.231)
Host is up (0.22s latency).
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
0/tcp     filtered unknown
65535/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.31 seconds
```

So perhaps there is another layer of firewall on the router? Or perhaps even on the larger WAN you are connected to? That’s my only guess at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought it was open, I'll check firewall settings.